# Dism error 87 "cleanup-image option is unknown"

Tags: windows-10, dism

Im in winPE trying to use:

```
dism /image:d:\ /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:d:\temp
```

on an offline image but cannot get past this error:

```
"Dism error 87 “cleanup-image option is unknown”.
```

I did the exact same procedure on windows 8 and a separate fresh install of windows 10 with no issues at all.

I've gone through all the Microsoft articles about dism i could find, many sites, and forum posts outlining the same handful of procedures that are supposed to fix this and other issues but don't seem to work half the time.

Supposedly error 87 is a syntax issue but this clearly doesn't apply to my situation. The error occurs with other options as well, /scanhealth, /checkhealth, /restorehealth, it isn't limited to just /cleanup-image.There appears to be no proven solution to this problem, if so its very hidden.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I just want to clarify a point, you ran the command, within a Windows 8 WinPE image?  Are we talking about Windows 8 or Windows 8.1? There should not be a huge difference between the DISM tool for Windows 8 and Windows 10 (in the context you are using it at least).  Are you using lowercase for the command or using the correct ("Online", "RestoreHealth"  "Cleanup-Image" "CheckHealth", etc).  You should also be using an Index number.  Instead of submitting a comment you should clarify your question by editing it.

Comment: 8.1. What do you mean "using the correct ("Online", "RestoreHealth" "Cleanup-Image" "CheckHealth", etc)" ? I didn't think case mattered for anything in this command, i dont recall paying any attention to case when running it on 8 either. The only place i've seen index numbers used was in mount commands.

Comment: I forgot a work, I was asking if you were using the correct capitalization for the command since the error indicates the command does not exist.  I can confirm that "Cleanup-Image" does indeed work within a Windows 10 WinPE image.  You need to mount the correct image within the .wim file if you want the command to work though.

Comment: Correct index number is being used in the mount command and proper syntax is being used. Its something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working, although im still not  sure what the issue was. I decided to start the whole thing over again, deleted the wim i had copied over from the disc and deleted the folder i had mounted the image to. I ran the exact same commands id been running. My only guess is that an error occurred the first time when copying the wim from the disc or while mounting the image.